# Dynamic validation of list of values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp

I have a form with dynamically generated input fields.In these input fields , some items are mandatory and needs to be filled in by the user.While submitting the form , i need to validate the form and check whether the mandatory fields are not empty.How can i achieve this using javascript? Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks for your valuable time and help

Comment: What happens for users that disable JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HTML 5, you can using the `required`attribute in the input tag else you can use something like below to verify each field before submit.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    var failed = false;
    $(".required").each(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        failed = true;
      }
    });
    
    if (failed) {
      alert("Mandatory field is empty!");
    } else {
      alert("Proceed");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="myFomr">
  <input name="text1" type="text" class="required" value=""><br>
  <input name="text2" type="text" value=""><br>
  <input name="text3" type="text" class="required" value=""><br>
<form>
<button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
```